# Dask groupby.agg -- workers keep restarting

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

**Background:**

I am working with a ~86 GB dataset on Dask with around 200 mil obs and ~55 columns (1428 partitions of ~0.45 GB each). The command I am having trouble with is `ddf.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg('sum').compute()`, which basically groups data by columns A and B and computes the sum of variables in the dataframe.

I am working on a local computer with a `LocalCluster` initialized as follows:

```
cluster = LocalCluster(memory_limit="40GB", silence_logs=logging.ERROR, threads_per_worker=3)
cluster.adapt(minimum=5, maximum=12)
```

**Error:**

While tracking performance on the dashboard, I see that the workers complete tasks for the groupby command above (see image below) [image: workers almost complete the tasks] but the whole process restarts right at the very end; it never goes on to `aggregate-agg` step (see the next image). [image: process restarts without concluding] This process is repeated 3 or 4 times after which I get a `KilledWorker` error.

**Solution:**

1. I thought it was a memory issue. So, I increased the allocated memory per worker from 20GB to 30GB to 40GB. Didn't work. The images are from the cluster with 40GB memory per worker
2. So I thought maybe it was a compute issue: I had too many threads initialized and so a lot of time was wasted transferring data. I reduced that to 3 threads per worker. No luck.
3. The one worker in yellow at the top makes me believe that perhaps I need to reduce the partition size. This is what I am going to try now but just wanted to reach out to see if people have ideas or have run into similar issues.

Happy to provide further information!

Comment: Hi, what types are columns A and B? And which variables do you have in the DataFrame (typically, do you have strings?). From the first screenshot, it looks like one of the aggregation is using too much memory on one of the worker. One of the final partition is too big to fit in memory, and thus the final reduce step of the aggregation is failing.

Comment: Did you solve it? I am struggling to get some help over dask too

Comment: @GuillaumeEB was right. It was a memory issue. Not sure why one partition was too big to fit, but I simply allocated more memory and it worked for this use case.